# Android Studio debugging "threads" window keeps refreshing

Tags: android, android-studio

It's content flashes then showing "Collecting data", again and again. No way to view, never say interract. How to fix this? Can I control the target via jdb simultaneously and how?
Android Studio version is 3.5.3.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a memory cache issue. Try to invalidate cache and restart. That should fix it.

> File > Invalidate cache and restart